# c# dictionary key partial

Tags: c#, dictionary, partial

I have a dictionary like that

```
 Key                  Value
 D:\test\ccc.csproj   1224
 D:\LOL\ppp.csproj    3467
```

Now when I’m searching for the key I have only part of the key which is the the project name (ccc or ppp) and not the exact key.
Can you help me change code so it will work ?

```
_Table = new Dictionary<string, string>();

if (_Table.ContainsKey(projectName.ToLower()) == true)
    return _Table[projectName.ToLower()];
else
    return null;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
var key = _Table.Keys.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Contains(projectName.ToLower()));
if (key != null)
{
    return _Table[key];
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```